# ImportError by standalone executable created by Python's Freeze tool

Tags: python, importerror

I have installed python2.7.10 in Linux Ubuntu.(I use source tarball)

```
./configure
make
```

I want to get an executable binary file to use in a remote server that does not have Python installed.

I used the command

```
python freeze.py -o ./dist_time Test_time.py
```

source code of 'Test_time.py':

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print
print "Current date and time using str method of datetime object:"
print str(now)

print
print "Current date and time using instance attributes:"
print "Current year: %d" % now.year
print "Current month: %d" % now.month
print "Current day: %d" % now.day
print "Current hour: %d" % now.hour
print "Current minute: %d" % now.minute
print "Current second: %d" % now.second
print "Current microsecond: %d" % now.microsecond

print
print "Current date and time using strftime:"
print now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

I receive 'Test_time' executable binary.

I moved the binary file(Test_time) to the remote server (where Python is not installed).

When I execute 'Test_time'binary file there, I get this error message:

```
./Test_time

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test_time.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

Why is the datetime module not built into the executable? How do I include the module in the executable file?

Comment: are you using virtualenv on the remote server?

Comment: What are you using to freeze?

Comment: @ Ayush Shanker  No, i just move 'time' file from local to remote server and  i use " ./time " command

Comment: The `datetime` module is always included in the python standard library after version 2.3. So, if you don't have it, then I suggest you upgrading your linux version on your server.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac  
my server linux version is 12.04. python version is 2.7.10
if python always include datetime module , why can't find datetime module?

Comment: @moooeeeep i copied 'time' executable file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cx_freeze` to create an executable from your script, it will generate a directory containing an executable and its dependances.
You need to create a `setup.py` in the same directory.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "posix":
    base = "Linux"

setup(  name = "times",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My demo application!",
        executables = [Executable("time.py", base=base)])
```

Then run it with this command `python setup.py build`.